# How to list chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm able to follow https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html

```
$ peer chaincode invoke ... -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'

2021-08-23 17:52:59.534 PST [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200
```

I leanred `peer chaincode list` can list chaincodes, but the following commands don't give expected result.

```
$ peer chaincode list -C mychannel --installed
Get installed chaincodes on peer:
$ peer chaincode list -C mychannel --instantiated
Get instantiated chaincodes on channel mychannel:
```

Given I've successfully deployed the basic chaincode, how do I see it through `peer chaincode list`?

Comment: these commands will work until HLF1.4 only.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue, will be with the path that is getting set. Make sure to export the following peer path where chaincode is installed :-

```
FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPDIR
```

If tls is enabled, export the following path along with the paths above

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
```

And then try the commands

```
peer chaincode list --installed
peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel
```

Comment: looks like I have to use `peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just view the installed chaincode below is the command for the HLF2.2x

> peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --peerAddresses localhost:7051
> --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE

If you want to view the commited chaincode list below is the command

> peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID channelName

in HLF2.2x chaincode lifecycle is introduced. So if you want to execute chaincode you need to approve and commit after installed on peer.